# Material dialog button click event misbehaving

Tags: android, dialog, material-design

Hello i'm using `affolestads` `material dialogs` in my app but recently I noticed something.The positive `button` click event sometimes behaves nicely but sometimes it just doesn't start my `AsyncTask` the first time so i have to click it again.

Check out my code and maybe highlight what i'm doing wrong:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_remove, menu);
    //menu hiding and invalidation
    this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
    MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.pay);
    if (mFruitList.size() > 0) {
        item.setVisible(true);
        item1.setVisible(true);
    }
    if (mSpicesList.size() > 0) {
        item.setVisible(true);
        item1.setVisible(true);
    }
    if (mVeggyList.size() > 0) {
        item.setVisible(true);
        item1.setVisible(true);
    }
    if (mCerealsList.size() > 0) {
        item.setVisible(true);
        item1.setVisible(true);
    }
    return true;
}

//delete selected items
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete:
            //item removal
            for (int i = mFruitList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (mFruitList.get(i).selected) {
                    Product selectedProduct = mFruitList.get(i);
                    FrtHelper.removeProduct(selectedProduct);
                    mFruitList.remove(selectedProduct);

                }
            }
            adapterFruit.notifyDataSetChanged();

            for (int i = mSpicesList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (mSpicesList.get(i).selected) {
                    Product selectedProduct = mSpicesList.get(i);
                    SpcHelper.removeProduct(selectedProduct);
                    mSpicesList.remove(selectedProduct);
                }
            }
            adapterSpices.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for (int i = mVeggyList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (mVeggyList.get(i).selected) {
                    Product selectedProduct = mVeggyList.get(i);
                    VgyHelper.removeProduct(selectedProduct);
                    mVeggyList.remove(i);
                }
            }
            adapterVeggies.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for (int i = mCerealsList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (mCerealsList.get(i).selected) {
                    Product selectedProduct = mCerealsList.get(i);
                    CrlHelper.removeProduct(selectedProduct);
                    mCerealsList.remove(i);
                }
            }
            adapterCereals.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        case R.id.pay:
            //price calculation
            adapterFruit.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapterCereals.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapterVeggies.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapterSpices.notifyDataSetChanged();

            int subTotal1 = 0;
            for (Product p : mFruitList) {
                int quantity = FrtHelper.getProductQuantity(p);
                subTotal1 += p.price * quantity;
            }

            int subTotal2 = 0;
            for (Product p : mSpicesList) {
                int quantity = SpcHelper.getProductQuantity(p);
                subTotal1 += p.price * quantity;
            }

            int subTotal3 = 0;
            for (Product p : mVeggyList) {
                int quantity = VgyHelper.getProductQuantity(p);
                subTotal1 += p.price * quantity;
            }

            int subTotal4 = 0;
            for (Product p : mCerealsList) {
                int quantity = CrlHelper.getProductQuantity(p);
                subTotal1 += p.price * quantity;
            }

            Total = subTotal1 + subTotal2 + subTotal3 + subTotal4;
            GrandTotal = (Total * 16 / 100) + Total;
            createPdf();
            ShowDialog("Place order worth" + " " + String.valueOf(GrandTotal));
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}

private void takeScreenShot() {

    try {
        View u = findViewById(R.id.recycler_parent);
        NestedScrollView z = findViewById(R.id.cart_layout);

        int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

        bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(u, totalWidth, totalHeight);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, totalWidth, totalHeight, true);

        Image image;

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/e-Nunua/" + "Order" + ".pdf";
        File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/e-Nunua/");
        if (!filepath.exists()) {
            final boolean mkdirs = filepath.mkdirs();
        }

        File myPath = new File(path);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        Document document = new Document(image);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(myPath));
        document.open();
        document.addAuthor("kamble");
        document.add(image);
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception i1) {
        i1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void ShowDialog(String title) {
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(CrtActivity.this)
            .content("Note that:\n\n1.This amount is inclusive of 16% tax.\n\n2.By clicking yes you agree to our terms of sales and are bound by them.Any action contrary to the terms after cognition of the request shall leave you liable to any action placed by the app owner.The full copy of the terms of sale and use can be found in the app settings.Please read and understand them before placing any order.\n\nClick yes to place order or no to cancel.")
            .title(title)
            .icon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.launcher))
            .positiveText("Yes")
            .negativeText("No!")
            .cancelable(false)
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    if (CtgActivity.isInternetWorking()) {
                        SendEmail sendEmail = new SendEmail();
                        sendEmail.execute();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please connect to a working network and retry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }).show();
}
```

I'm calling it from `menu item` click and the two `AsyncTasks` are executed.One while the `dialog` launches and the other in the click event of the `dialog` button.

Comment: post the error logs

Comment: its not an error.Ok the problem is that when you click the button the first time,the async does not execute but when you click the second time,then it executes

Comment: make the title globel variable and  showdailog not receive any thing ..may be that make the latency

Comment: what do you mean by showdialog not receive anything?I didnt get that part

Comment: i mean void like this showdailog()

Comment: oh ok.let me try that right now.Ill get back to you.I looked at the comment again and got what you meant

Comment: wow.thanks bro.Its working now.Maybe add this as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: good for You..I added it as answer it may help somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let `ShowDialog()` not receive the title ..make the title global variable...if not ok...put the calculation inside the `ShowDialog()` ...it may be caused the latency.